# Calling hooks multiple times in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a hook that counts the number of posts of a user and returns the result:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from './Firebase.js';

//--------------------------------------------------------------/
//
//
// This hook returns the number of posts of a user 
// with a specific userUid
//
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------/
const useNumberOfPosts = (userUid) => {

    const [posts, setPosts]   = useState(0);

    useEffect( () => { 

        // API call
        firebase.database().ref('posts/').on('value', snapshot => { 

            // Code to count the number of posts (not relevant)
            setPosts(counter);

        });

    }, [userUid]);

    return posts;
}

export default useNumberOfPosts;
```

This hook is working fine.

### Problem

The problem comes when I try to call the hook multiple times (several user Uids). Ideally, I would want to do something like:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect }   from 'react';
import useNumberOfPosts                 from './useNumberOfPosts.js';
import firebase                         from './Firebase.js';

//--------------------------------------------------------------/
//
// This hook returns list of users ordered by posts
//
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------/
const useRankingUsers = () => {

    const [ranking, setRanking] = useState(null);

    useEffect( () => { 

        firebase.database().ref('users/').once('value').then( snapshot => {

            if(snapshot) {

                var users  = snapshot.val();

                // Mapping users and getting points
                Object.keys(users).map( uid => {

                    let posts   = useNumberOfPosts(uid);
                    // Insert posts into array

                });

                // Sort array
                // Set new state


            }


        }) 

    }, []);

    return ranking;
}

export default useRankingUsers;
```

I know that I can't call hooks inside useEffect, but I need to get an array of Uids before calling `useNumberOfPosts(userUid)` multiple times.

The question is: How can I call the hook multiple times from `useRankingUsers()`?

Comment: You could accept an array of `ids` instead of just one inside `getNumberOfPosts`. Also the convention is that custom hooks must start with 'use': `useNumberofPosts`.

Comment: Previously to call `useNumberOfPosts`, I need to get the array of `ids` via API call. So I would  need to use the hook inside `useEffect` and React doesn't allow it.

Comment: @ErikMartínJordán You will have to store the ids in a state after fetching them and use another effect that triggers when the ids change. You do not need to nest hooks.